# NumLock light on permanently on keyboard attached to Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, keyboard

I have a regular keyboard plugged into my Latitude notebook. The Num Lock light is ALWAYS on. If you press the Num Lock key nothing happens. How do I fix this so that the Num Lock key toggles Num Lock on and off, as it is supposed to.

Comment: Can you give the laptop model number? What happens when you press NUM LOCK **on the laptop**? How do CAPS LOCK and SCROLL LOCK behave?

Comment: Its a Latitude E6340. Nothing happens when you press the Num Lock key. The caps lock key works, but the light does not go on and off, it is just off permanently. I am not sure how to test the Scroll Lock key, but its light is off, and when you press the Scroll Lock key the light does not go on.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to change the numlock status in the bios, although it does not specify usb or laptop keyboard, the option tends to work for external keyboards only.